Unable to sign in a new user that was created using node js and firebase-admin
Goal: create a user and sign in after that. simple as that.
I created the user usinf nodejs and firebase-admin with the standard function that work just fine:
createUser: function (fullName, email, password) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            firebase.auth().createUser({
                    email: email,
                    emailVerified: false,
                    password: password,
                    displayName: fullName,
                    disabled: false
                }).then(function(userRecord) {
                    resolve(userRecord);
                    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    resolve({res: 'error', error});
                    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
                });
        })
    },

When I debug the user is created in the firebase authentication and in my db, and I'm using the simple POST from firebase doc
const signInUrl = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=${apiKey}`;
                const requestData = {
                    email: values.email,
                    password: values.password,
                    returnSecureToken: true,
                }
                
                fetch(signInUrl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                })

Somehow when I create the account manually that works, but not if I'm using firebase-admin from node js
This is the response I got in the client after trying to sign in
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}

All the code was debugged and all the variables and params are fine

UPDATE:
All was a typing error in my side, everything work as expected.
